# Inconsistent number of arguments in formatting string

Tags: android, lint

I am getting following Lint warning:

Inconsistent number of arguments in formatting string 'mystring'; found both 0 and 2

on following android string:

```
<string name="mystring">blablabla because %1$s.\n\nDo you want to delete this item? \n\n%2$s</string>
```

Does this make sense for you? I'm not understanding why and why 0 and 2 and not 1 and 2?

Comment: Does your code have multiple strings.xml file for translations? Please check all the translations of "sp_call_quarantine_item_format" string. In some translation of this string, there are zero number of argument.

Answer (score 1):

This type of warning normally happens when format strings used, have different number of arguments defined across translations. when a language is not translated or updated correctly.

Please check for number of arguments in all the translations of "sp_call_quarantine_item_format" string. In some translation of this string, there are zero number of argument.

Comment: I checked and in each translations there is the same 1 and 2, no 0 whatsoever

Comment: The problem is not with %1 or %2. It is with the count of the arguments you are using in the string. All of your translation strings.xml should have "sp_call_quarantine_item_format"  string and all should have total 2 formatting arguments(%s variables).

Comment: Hmm, strange, because all my strings have the same amount of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was simply incorrect character for Japanese translation. Somehow Lint didn't like `%d`, but accept `%d`. Not sure if it's correctly shown here on SO.

[image]